# get return value in callback(in angular directive) when a api is called from controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have created one directive in Angularjs in which I need to use getUsers() method, so that I can call Controller's Function.

Controller's function is called.But Controller's Function is returning some an api call's response.I want to get that response in callback function.How to achieve that?

Below is my code:
IN DIRECTIVE-
$scope.getUsers({partnerID:obj._id});

IN CONTROLLER

```
scope.getUsers = function(id){

        if(id){
            var searchObj = {};
            searchObj.role = "serviceagent";
            searchObj.partner_id = id;
            userinfoFactory.get('',searchObj).then(function(data){
                $scope.phlebos = angular.copy(data.response);

            })
        }
    }
```

I want to return $scope.phlebos.

How will I do that ??

Comment: You can simply return the response. `return data`. See if this help.

Comment: i tried, but did not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try with [Promises](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) and do something like this in your Controller :

```
scope.getUsers = function(id){
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    if(id){
        var searchObj = {};
        searchObj.role = "serviceagent";
        searchObj.partner_id = id;
        userinfoFactory.get('',searchObj).then(function(data){
            $scope.phlebos = angular.copy(data.response);
            deferred.resolve($scope.phlebos);
        })
    }
    return deffered.promise;
}
```

And in your directive :

```
$scope.getUsers({partnerID:obj._id}).then(function(response) {
    // Do whatever you want with the returned value
});
```

Comment: I tried this, but got typeerror saying .then(function(response){}) of undefined

Comment: @HetalSangoi Did you inject `$q` in your controller ?

Comment: Great ! The previous error was because I wrote `deffered.promise` instead of `deferred.promise` no ?